# Convert a polar equation into parametric

Tags: polar-coordinates, parametric

I am getting hung up on the terminology in Calc 2 and making this subject much harder than it needs to be.

Question: Convert $r=7\sin(\theta)-2$ into parametric.

Does that simply mean putting it into the $x, y$ form?

$x=r\cos(\theta)$ --> $$x=(7\sin(\theta)-2)(\cos(\theta))$$
$y=r\sin(\theta)$ --> $$y=(7\sin(\theta)-2)(\sin(\theta))$$

Comment: Yes, you've got it.

You might like to check out the MathJax tutorial, which will help you typeset equations in your question statements more readable: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Thank you for your help with the math, I most definetly was making this harder than it is! The link is great as well, I was wondering how others got there equations to turn out so nice, thank you for sharing.

Answer (score 1):

Consider $r = 7 \sin(\theta)$,

\begin{align*}
r^2 &= 7r \sin(\theta)\\
x^2 + y^2 &= 7y\\
x^2 &= 7y - y^2
\end{align*}

Hence $x^2 = t$ and $7y - y^2 = t$. Using quadratic equation, we have
$$x = \pm \sqrt{t} \hspace{30pt} \mbox{and} \hspace{30pt} y = \frac{7 \pm \sqrt{49 - 4t}}{2}$$

Answer (score 0):

We can solve this problem with Mathematica:

```
CoordinateTransform[ 
     "Polar" -> "Cartesian", {7 Sin[θ] - 2, θ}]
```

[image]